# Commutators, automorphisms, and the center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working through the book "The Theory of Finite Groups" by Hans Kurzweil and Bernd Stellmacher. I'm stuck on Section 1.6, Exercise 4:

Let $ \alpha \in Aut(G).   $ Suppose that $x^{-1}\alpha(x) \in Z(G)$ for all $x \in G$.  Then $ \alpha (x) = x$ for all $x \in G' := \left< [x, y] \mid x, y \in G \right>.  $

Defns:
$[x, y] = x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$

and $ Z(G)=\{ x \in G \mid g^{-1} x g =x$ for all $g \in G\}$

As far as I've gotten:
$[x, y] \in G'$.
Then $ [x, y]^{-1} \alpha ([x, y]) \in Z(G)$

so $ g^{-1} [x, y]^{-1} \alpha ([x, y])g=[x, y]^{-1} \alpha ([x, y])$ for all $g \in G$

so $ g^{-1} [y, x] \alpha ([x, y])g=[y, x] \alpha ([x, y])$ for all $g \in G$

Then $g^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}yx \alpha (y^{-1}) \alpha (x^{-1}) \alpha(y)\alpha(x) g=y^{-1}x^{-1}yx \alpha (y^{-1}) \alpha (x^{-1}) \alpha(y)\alpha(x)$

I suspect that I need to find some value for $g$ that will give the required relationship, but I haven't been able to find it.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It suffices to prove $\alpha([x,y])=[x,y]$ for all $x$ and $y$.

$\alpha(x)=xg$ and $\alpha(y)=yh$ where $g$, $h\in Z(G)$.

Then
$$\alpha([x,y])=[\alpha(x),\alpha(y)]=[xg,yh]
=(xg)^{-1}(yh)^{-1}(xg)(yh)=g^{-1}x^{-1}h^{-1}y^{-1}xgyh
=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=[x,y]$$
using the fact that $g$ and $h$ commute with everything, being elements of the centre.